# A program that prints the number of asterisks that the user inputs using a function and passing value to the function

Tags: c, function, c-strings

A part of an assignment I have due. The assignment states -

Write a program that prints 5 bar graphs with asterisks. A function that accepts the length (number of asterisks) should be created and then called 5 different times to print the graphs. Use input validation to make sure that a user enters a positive number that is less than or equal to 50. Create a function that accepts an integer value representing the amount of asterisks to print. Only 1 value should be passed to the function. Use a for loop inside the function to print the number of asterisks that corresponds to the number passed to the function

I have this so far but I am struggling pretty badly when it comes to functions. I am unsure of what my next step would be and how to print the number of asterisks inputted by the user.

Thank you for your help. I am just a student!

```
#include <stdio.h>
//function prototype
void graph(int numberOfAsterisks);

int main(void){
// declare variables for length of each chart
int chart1;
int chart2;
int chart3;
int chart4;
int chart5;
// declare loop variable
int i;

// prompt the user and get lengths of each graph do/while to repeat if invalid
do {
printf("How long is chart 1? ");
scanf("%d", &chart1);
} while (chart1 >= 50);

do {
printf("How long is chart 2? ");
scanf("%d", &chart2);
} while (chart2 >= 50);

do {
printf("How long is chart 3? ");
scanf("%d", &chart3);
} while (chart3 >= 50);

do {
printf("How long is chart 4? ");
scanf("%d", &chart4);
} while (chart4 >= 50);

do {
printf("How long is chart 5? ");
scanf("%d", &chart5);
} while (chart5 >= 50);

//blank space
printf("\n");

// display numbers of asterisks

    printf("1. %d| ", chart1);
        for( i=0; i< chart1; i++)
        {
             printf("*");
        }

    printf("\n");
    printf("1. %d| ", chart2);
    for( i=0; i< chart2; i++)
        {
             printf("*");
        }

    printf("\n");
    printf("1. %d| ", chart3);
    for( i=0; i< chart3; i++)
        {
             printf("*");
        }

    printf("\n");
    printf("1. %d| ", chart4);
    for( i=0; i< chart4; i++)
        {
             printf("*");
        }

    printf("\n");
    printf("1. %d| ", chart5);
    for( i=0; i< chart5; i++)
        {
             printf("*");
        }

    printf("\n");



}
```

Comment: Do the "bar graphs" have to be printed next to each other or just after each input? Have you learned arrays?

Comment: So far so good: but you need to call the function 5 times, once for each of the 5 values you have entered, such as `graph(chart1);` and so on. Change the function (and its prototype) to a `void` type, no need to return any value. For starters just print how many asterisks, like `void graph(int numberOfAsterisks){ printf("%d\n", numberOfAsterisks);}`. Then do as they say, and make a loop inside the function to print that number of asterisks (and a `newline`).

Comment: I have the program working without using a function now its just a matter of converting what I have to a program using a function.

Comment: Could go directly with `printf("%.*s\n", width_up_to_50, "*** 50 stars ***");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` is also a function, so you don't have problems with functions.

All you need to do now is put your code that's repeating into `graph` function like this:

```
void graph(int numberOfAsterisks) {
    printf("1. %d| ", numberOfAsterisks);
    for( i=0; i< numberOfAsterisks; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
}
```

And then just call `graph(chart1)` (*for example*) in `main`.

Comment: Perfect! How do I increment my count though? I have played around and can only get it to display 1. on each line

Comment: @MissAnnThropic use global variable `int cnt=0` which you would increment inside `graph` function, and than print it. Other option is to have counter as local static variable inside `graph` function (`static int cnt=0`).